# How can I send messages directly to a group?

Tags: adb, whatsapp

I need help sending text to a particular group using the adb shell.
Searching the forums here, I found the code below:

```
adb shell am start -n com.whatsapp/.Main 
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -t  text/plain -e jid 
    'xxxxxxxxxxx@s.whatsapp.net' --eu android.intent.extra.STREAM 
    file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20181025_223214.jpg  -p com.whatsapp
```

the question is:

1. How to identify a group's JID.
2. How to change this code to send a text instead of a file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Groups jid you can get in messages.db at chat_list table by gorup name (subject column) or at messages table by message text. it will be like `77787987018-1602484814@g.us`.
2. To send text u can use this command:

`am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -t text/plain -e jid {user jid} -e android.intent.extra.TEXT "{text}" -p {whatsapp packet name}`